# ASP.NET Web App hosting configuration requirements

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, virtual-machine

We are finnishing with our Web application and looking for a good way to host it. We are offered VM and need to specify good configuration for it.

So, as i can say, we need IIS 8.0 and MS SQL Server 2008.  But what else?

What is the "required configuration" ?  We expect around 50,000 monthly visitors.

Thanks, if I was unclear about this please let me know, we need to handle this asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you should get at least 4/8 GB RAM and 2 HDD depending on your needs - one for backups and one with your server, aslo et one Plesk so to manage your server easier. If you have not any admin knowledge then it will much better to get managed VPS hosting.